# Highlight 2 rows by class or ID in separate tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rows, highlight

I am creating two tables dynamically in PHP and I want to be able to easily compare rows in the two tables. I want to be able to hover highlight a row in either table and the corresponding row (by id) in the other table highlight as well.

I've found MANY references to similar situations on here, but they all seem to work by hover on row 1 will highlight row 1 in table 2. I want the highlight to function by row ID (or class, not sure which is more appropriate).

In the example below if I hover over the row id 123 in table 1, row id 123 in table 2 would also highlight. And the reverse, highlighting row id 123 in table 2 would highlight the row id 123 in table 1.

The trick here is that these rows may be in any sort of order, so counting or doing nth stuff wont work here.

```
<table id="t1">
    <tr id="123"><td>......</td></tr>
    <tr id="456"><td>......</td></tr>
    <tr id="789"><td>......</td></tr>
    <tr id="0AB"><td>......</td></tr>
    <tr id="CDE"><td>......</td></tr>
</table>
<p>Table 2</p>
<table id="t2">
    <tr id="CDE"><td>......</td></tr>
    <tr id="123"><td>......</td></tr>
    <tr id="0AB"><td>......</td></tr>
    <tr id="456"><td>......</td></tr>
    <tr id="789"><td>......</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm crap with Javascript and jQuery. Just at a total loss at this point. Trying to hack other solutions together to work is beyond me at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Id` can not be repeated within single HTML document. Hence modify your HTML to make use of `class` instead of `id`. And then you can refer below code for your logic:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table tr").hover(function() {
      $("tr").removeClass("highlight");
      $("." + $(this).attr("class")).addClass("highlight");
    },
    function() {

      $("." + ($(this).attr("class").split(' '))[0]).removeClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t1">
  <tr class="123">
    <td>......</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="456">
    <td>......</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="789">
    <td>......</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="0AB">
    <td>......</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="CDE">
    <td>......</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>Table 2</p>
<table id="t2">
  <tr class="CDE">
    <td>......</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="123">
    <td>......</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="0AB">
    <td>......</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="456">
    <td>......</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="789">
    <td>......</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

for starters, an ID should be unique - so you're out of luck matching on those. Replace them with class or data attributes, e.g.

```
<table>
    <tr data-set="123"><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr data-set="abc"><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr data-set="xyz"><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr data-set="987"><td>...</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr data-set="123"><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr data-set="abc"><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr data-set="xyz"><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr data-set="987"><td>...</td></tr>
</table>
```

then something like this, you basically get the data attribute of the element you're hovering on, and search for other elements with the same data attribute.

https://jsfiddle.net/yqm0z5up/1/

Excuse the sloppy nature of the code, but should be enough to get you looking in the right places.

Comment: Thank you. This works and is easy to tease apart and follow. i appreciate it.